# Is there a way to exhaustively check a union type with a type guard, and enforce it with the compiler?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am trying to write a typeguard function and have the compiler help me ensure I never forget to add a new case.  Here is the scenario:

I start out with:

```js
type Operation = '+' | '-';

function isOperation(value: string): value is Operation {
  switch(value) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

This is not very helpful, as if I add a new string to the union, it will still compile.  I can also add any string to the case statements (ie `case 'foo':`) and it will still compile.  Let's solve the latter:

```js
function isOperation(value: string): value is Operation {
  switch(value as Operation) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
      return true;
  }
}
```

Ok, this now compiles, and if I forget to add a case if I were to add `*` as a new operator, the compiler would complain.  I also no longer have to worry about putting in a case that doesn't actually exist, as the compile will complain about that as well.

However, the signature of the method is a bit of a lie (it is technically `(value is Operation) | undefined`, so let's add this:

```js
function isOperation(value: string): value is Operation {
  switch(value as Operation) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Great, that solves everything, except there is now a pesky warning at the `return false;`: `Unreachable code detected.ts(7027)`.  I treat warnings as errors, so the compiler will complain about this, and I don't want to disable the `unreachableCode` compiler check as a whole, just in this one instance.

So my question is: what is the right way to do this as a type guard?

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting issue.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N54qPw), which should produce warnings if you make a mistake, but it's not really the kind of thing you'd do conventionally.  I'd be more inclined to define `Operation` in terms of the runtime thing you're using to check, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDPXRN).  Let me know if either of these are something you'd want to see in an answer.